Using the Past Perfect instead of the Past Perfect continuous
I wonder why the author used past perfect there

and he spoke with some authority, for he had tended the garden at Bag
End for forty years

Shouldn't we use past perfect continuous, because it lasted forty years? I also read that the past perfect suggests something more permanent than the past perfect continuous. Does the above example show just such a case? If so, what if it was not forty years, but one?
(I'm not trying to correct Mr.Tolkien)

You could use past perfect continuous (...for he had been tending the garden...), but you certainly don't need to - it's just a stylistic choice. Anyway, I don't know the full context, but if he'd been retired for some time before the cited text, it would be very poor style to use past perfect continuous.

...in fact, I just checked. It's Tolkien, writing about Hamfast Gamgee - who was himself growing old and stiff in the joints, the job was mainly carried on by his youngest son, Sam Gamgee. So obviously he isn't really tending the garden any more. The moral of this story is Don't try to find fault with Tolkien's text!

I didn't try to correct Tolkien, I know he was a linguist. I just wanted someone to explain it. So it's not necessary to use PPC if we note the duration of the action, if I understand it correctly. Could you please  explain why it would be poor style?

Shouldn't we use past perfect continuous? reads to me like I think we should use pat perfect continuous. But my first comment (made before identifying the relevant context) clearly explains not only that there is no concept of "should" here - it even points out the specific context where the exact form as used is the better stylistic choice (which I then discover is the cited context). You use Past Perfect Continuous for an action that continues right up to the current "narrative reference time", which isn't really the case here with a retired gardener.

Note that the cited text would still be syntactically valid without for forty years. And whether that "duration of the action" is specified or not makes no difference to the stylistic choice regarding which form of verb to use.

By "Shouldn't we use..." I only wanted to point the reason I was confused there. But I think I see now, thank you!

he spoke with some authority, for he had tended the garden at Bag End for forty years. The tending precedes the speaking.

The main point to note is that your point about past perfect suggests something more permanent than the past perfect continuous is incorrect. What matters, as I said, is You use Past Perfect Continuous for an action that continues right up to the current "narrative reference time". Regardless of whether the action lasted for centuries, decades or for minutes.

Yes, I think it's clear now. I misinterpreted past perfect continuous. Forgive my confusion here

Well, I'm not actually sorry. I asked politely more explanation without any thought of correcting Tolkien. I'm not native speaker, so I didn't get it from the first, but you responded arrogantly for some reason. I know, 2 days passed, but whatever

I'm tired of that, why you have to be so arrogant impatient rams. Just everywhere.

I. Past Perfect vs. Past Perfect Continuous.
To understand the difference between these tenses, let's consider the following example:

"He spoke with some authority, for he had tended the garden at Bag End for forty years."
"He spoke with some authority, for he had been tending the garden at Bag End for forty years."

In this case, there is a clear difference in meaning between the two:
The first sentence (Past Perfect) emphasizes the finished nature of the action: he had stopped tending the garden.
The first sentence (Past Perfect) may imply that the action was finished (the gardener had retired) or simply highlight that it occurred prior to the moment of speaking and lasted forty years. Whether he had stopped permanently or was still tending the garden is not explicitly stated and depends on the context.
The second sentence (Past Perfect Continuous) suggests the action was ongoing: he was still tending the garden when he spoke.
II. When the Difference is Minimal
In some cases, the Past Perfect Continuous and Past Perfect can be used interchangeably, with only a slight difference in emphasis rather than meaning.
For example:

Past Perfect:
"He had worked there for 1 year before the company shut down."

Emphasis: The action (working) is seen as completed before the company shut down.

Past Perfect Continuous:
"He had been working there for 1 year before the company shut down."

Emphasis: The action (working) is seen as ongoing when the company shut down.

Thank you for good answer!

I don't agree that Past Perfect emphasizes the finished nature of the action. In the text as cited, the only difference is that Past Perfect Continuous emphasizes the continuation of the action right up to (and possibly beyond) the current narrative reference time (in this case, the time when he spoke). The non-continuous version is "agnostic" as to whether the action is ongoing or not. Consider the possibility that he's pontificating "with authority" about smoking a pipe rather than a cigar ...for he had smoked using the same pipe for 40 years (he may or may not have quit smoking).

That's a silly objection. It just so happens that in the context of a "professional" gardener, we can meaningfully speak of him "finishing" the action (by retiring, not by having completed the act of maintaining the garden). But the syntax and the significance of the verb form choice is exactly the same with him smoking a pipe, even though it makes little sense to speak of finishing that action.

...and what's with "There is no Past Perfect Continuous"? It's in the OP, my comment, and your answer. The whole point of the question is to differentiate Past Perfect Continuous from Simple Past.

@FumbleFingers I mean in the original text. This is considered to explain the difference. What is the point in bringing another sentence. Talk with reference to context without creating confusion
